# iPad - Custom Movie Player Like GQ Magazine App

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk, movieplayer

I'm developing an iPad magazine App.

While researching other apps I thought the GQ one was the best.

I would like to implement a similar custom movie player in my app. It would include a Play button, pause button, stop button, and slidebar along with the player.

I'm looking for ideas on how GQ implements a player like this or how I may go about creating my own.

Comment: Oh, I Guess there isn't GQ App in US Appstore.
Never mind about the App.
Just wanna make custom movie player with new button and slide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/)

[UIButton](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/)

[UISlider](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/)

Comment: I meant the button as a button that belongs to MoviePlayer standard UI. is that really that simple to change the UIButton customary in the MoviePlayer UI?

Comment: No, but you can put the movie player’s view inside your own view and overlay buttons on it yourself. Hook those up to IBAction methods that call the movie player’s `-play`, `-pause`, etc., and there you have it.

Comment: Thank you, I think I found a solution on your answer!